# mysql - how to delete records with condition

Tags: mysql

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `order`
    (`order_id` int, `order_status_id` int, `ip` varchar(11), `date_added` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO `order`
    (`order_id`, `order_status_id`, `ip`, `date_added`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, '192.168.1.1', '2016-12-07 00:00:00'),
    (2, 0, '192.168.1.1', '2016-12-07 00:00:00'),
    (3, 0, '192.168.1.1', '2016-12-07 00:00:00'),
    (4, 0, '192.168.1.1', '2016-12-07 00:00:00'),
    (5, 1, '192.168.1.1', '2016-12-07 00:00:00'),

    (6, 0, '192.168.1.2', '2016-12-08 00:00:00'),
    (7, 0, '192.168.1.2', '2016-12-08 00:00:00'),
    (8, 0, '192.168.1.2', '2016-12-08 00:00:00'),
    (9, 0, '192.168.1.2', '2016-12-08 00:00:00'),
    (10, 1, '192.168.1.2', '2016-12-08 00:00:00'),

    (11, 0, '192.168.1.3', '2016-12-09 00:00:00'),
    (12, 0, '192.168.1.3', '2016-12-09 00:00:00'),
    (13, 0, '192.168.1.3', '2016-12-09 00:00:00'),
    (14, 0, '192.168.1.3', '2016-12-09 00:00:00'),
    (15, 0, '192.168.1.3', '2016-12-09 00:00:00');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20c0f

I expect sql erase all records except records where order_id are: 5, 10, 15

Explanations: I would like to erase records which has order_status_id = 0 with conditions:

a) if one of the record (from same ip/date_added order_id) has order_status_id = 1, then erase all records which has order_status_id = 0 (from same ip/date_added).  In my example records 1-4 and 6-9 should be deleted.

b) if there are no record from same ip/date_added with order_id = 1 (all records has order_status_id = 0), then leave one record with the highest order_id (all other deleted). In my example records 11-14 should be deleted.

Comment: That's some pretty specific requirements. **What have you tried**?

Comment: This code works for condition a) not b) delete o
    from `order` o join
         (select ip, date_added
          from `order` o
          where order_status_id = 1
          group by ip, date_added
         ) oo
         on o.ip = oo.ip and o.date_added = oo.date_added
    where o.order_status_id = 0;

Comment: and this one partly works for condition b) but not for a) delete n1 FROM `order` n1, `order` n2 
    WHERE n1.order_id > n2.order_id 
    AND n1.order_status_id = '0' 
    AND n2.order_status_id = '0' 
    AND n1.ip = n2.ip
    AND Day(n1.date_added) = Day(n2.date_added)

Comment: You also have a serious issue here in that your IP field is way too short. An IPv4 address needs 15 characters: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. IPv6 needs even more. Just use `VARCHAR(255)` to avoid truncation issues.

Comment: actually in DB I have real ip's varchar(40). In my example just as example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/QYWMI25232)**

First you need separate your condition. You have `{ip,date}` with `order_status_id {0,1}`

```
-- first filter
SELECT `ip`, `date_added`
FROM `order`
GROUP BY `ip`, `date_added`
HAVING MAX(`order_status_id`) = 1;

-- second filter    
SELECT `ip`, `date_added`
FROM `order`
GROUP BY `ip`, `date_added`
HAVING MAX(`order_status_id`) = 0;
```

**First delete**
You delete everyone matching the first filter but only those with `order_status_id = 0` meaning you left the one with `1`

```
DELETE o
FROM `order` o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `ip`, `date_added`
    FROM `order`
    GROUP BY `ip`, `date_added`
    HAVING MAX(`order_status_id`) = 1
) filter
  ON o.`ip` = filter.`ip`
 AND o.`date_added` = filter.`date_added`
WHERE o.`order_status_id` = 0;
```

**Second  delete**
You delete everyone matching second filter, but leave the one who doesnt have any id higher than him.

```
DELETE o1
FROM `order` o1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `ip`, `date_added`
    FROM `order`
    GROUP BY `ip`, `date_added`
    HAVING MAX(`order_status_id`) = 0
) filter
  ON o1.`ip` = filter.`ip`
 AND o1.`date_added` = filter.`date_added`
LEFT JOIN `order` o2
  ON o1.`order_id` < o2.`order_id`
WHERE o2.`ip` IS NOT NULL;
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: That works! Thank you very big master! Thank you very much for the explonation!!!

Comment: would you please help me one more time? In my real table date format is with hours minutes and secods (2016-12-08 12:23:53) so I need to compare just Y-m-d without h:m:s. I tried to adopt yous sql request as follows (but it doesn't work because of erron in 'on clause'):

Comment: delete o FROM `order` o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `ip`, Day(`date_added`), Month(`date_added`)
    FROM `order`
    GROUP BY `ip`, Day(`date_added`), Month(`date_added`)
    HAVING MAX(`order_status_id`) = 1
) filter
  ON o.`ip` = filter.`ip`
 AND Day(o.`date_added`) = Day(filter.`date_added`)
 AND Month(o.`date_added`) = Month(filter.`date_added`)
WHERE o.`order_status_id` = 0;